# how to make a script parser in python

Tags: python, parsing, text

i have data file .txt

```
name  : jashon m l
Address  : 2410 Vance Avenue
City       : Alexandria
State    : Louisiana
Zip code : 71301
Phone    : +3187305018

name  : rush b
Address  : address 2
City       : city 2
State    : state 2
Zip code : 71301
Phone    : phone
```

and i want make like this

```
jashon m l|2410 Vance Avenue|Alexandria|Louisiana|71301|+3187305018
rush b|address 2|city 2|state 2|71301|phone
```

help to make a script parser in python

Comment: Oops! Looks like you forgot to post the code that's troubling you

Comment: Is there any particular part of this you are stuck on? I would think 1) Open the file `with open("file.txt", "r") as f1` 2) read the file in `lines = f1.readlines()` 3) loop through the lines `for line in lines:` 4) if the line isn't blank, append the ` line.split(":")[1]` to a variable, if the line IS blank, append the variable to the output variable. 5) once done processing append what's left in the variable to the output variable 6) print that out, or write to a file.

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following -

Read the file:

```
with open(TEXT_FILE_PATH, "r") as file_handle:
  data = file_handle.read()
```

Get the processed text:

```
all_person_details = []
for person_details in data.split("\n\n"): # Split when there are two nextlines for different person
  all_entities = []
  for entity in person_details.split("\n"): # Split when there is one nextline for different person details
    _, value = entity.split(":") # Get the part after the colon
    value = value.strip() # Remove extra spaces from start or end
    all_entities.append(value)
  all_person_details.append("|".join(all_entities))
all_person_details = "\n".join(all_person_details)
```

Save the updated text:

```
with open(TEXT_FILE_PATH, "w") as fh:
  fh.write(all_person_details)
```